Tensorflow Error in final iteration: Input to reshape is a tensor with 28 values, but the requested shape has 128
def DMRL(n_users, n_items, embed_dim, n_factors):
    assert embed_dim % n_factors == 0, "embed_dim must be divisible by n_factors"
    
    user_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='UserInput')
    user_embedding = Embedding(n_users, embed_dim, name='UserEmbedding')(user_input)
    users = Flatten(name='UserFlatten')(user_embedding)
    
    item_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='ItemInput')
    item_embedding = Embedding(n_items, embed_dim, name='ItemEmbedding')(item_input)
    items = Flatten(name='ItemFlatten')(item_embedding)

    textual_input = Input(shape=(768,), name='TextualInput')
    textual_mlp = Modal_MLP(embed_dim, 4)(textual_input)

    visual_input = Input(shape=(4096,), name='VisualInput')
    visual_mlp = Modal_MLP(embed_dim, 4)(visual_input)
    
    user_factor_embedding = tf.split(users, n_factors, 1)
    item_factor_embedding = tf.split(items, n_factors, 1)
    textual_factor_embedding = tf.split(textual_mlp, n_factors, 1)
    visual_factor_embedding = tf.split(visual_mlp, n_factors, 1)

    #Disentangled Representation Learning
    cor_loss = CorrelationLossLayer(n_factors)([visual_factor_embedding, textual_factor_embedding, user_factor_embedding, item_factor_embedding])

    # Factor Interaction
    rating = FactorInteractionLayer(n_factors)([user_factor_embedding, item_factor_embedding, textual_factor_embedding, visual_factor_embedding])
    rating = Flatten()(rating)

    output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(rating)
    
    model = Model(inputs=[user_input, item_input, textual_input, visual_input], outputs=[output, cor_loss])

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01),
                  loss=[mse_loss, cor_loss_dummy],  
                  loss_weights=[1.0, 0.2])
    return model

def mse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()(y_true, y_pred)

def cor_loss_dummy(y_true, y_pred):
    return y_pred

emebd_dim = 128
n_factors = 2
batch_size = emebd_dim//n_factors

    model.fit([train_user, train_item, train_text, train_image],
                    [train_y, tf.zeros_like(train_y)],  
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=50,
                    callbacks=[es],
                    validation_split=0.1)


train_user shape: (275232,)
train_item shape: (275232,)
train_text shape: (275232, 768)
train_image shape: (275232, 4096)
train_y.shape: (275232,)
An error is always occurred in last iteration with this message:
Input to reshape is a tensor with 28 values, but the requested shape has 128
I expected the error is occurred in the FactorInteractionLayer class.
class FactorInteractionLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_factors):
        super(FactorInteractionLayer, self).__init__()
        self.n_factors = n_factors
        self.h = Dense(3, activation='tanh')
        self.user_sig = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
        self.text_sig = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
        self.visual_sig = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
        self.attention_layer = Dense(3, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, inputs):
        user_embedding, item_embedding, text_embedding, visual_embedding = inputs[0], inputs[1], inputs[2], inputs[3]

        output = 0
        for i in range(self.n_factors):
            user_emb, item_emb, text_emb, visual_emb = user_embedding[i], item_embedding[i], text_embedding[i], visual_embedding[i]

            user_item_text_visual = Concatenate()([user_emb, item_emb, text_emb, visual_emb])
            h = self.h(user_item_text_visual)
            attention_weights = self.attention_layer(h)

            user_item = tf.matmul(user_emb, item_emb)
            user_item = self.user_sig(user_item)
            user_text = tf.matmul(user_emb, text_emb)
            user_text = self.text_sig(user_text)
            user_visual = tf.matmul(user_emb, visual_emb)
            user_visual = self.visual_sig(user_visual)

            user_item_importance = attention_weights[:, 0]
            user_text_importance = attention_weights[:, 1]
            user_visual_importance = attention_weights[:, 2]

            user_item_imp = tf.tensordot(user_item, user_item_importance, axes=0)
            user_text_imp = tf.tensordot(user_text, user_text_importance, axes=0)
            user_visual_imp = tf.tensordot(user_visual, user_visual_importance, axes=0)

            sum_concat = Concatenate()([user_item_imp, user_text_imp, user_visual_imp])

            output += tf.reduce_sum(sum_concat)
        output = tf.expand_dims(output, -1)
        return output

But there is some additional messages above the error message:
Node: 'gradient_tape/model/ItemEmbedding/embedding_lookup/Reshape_1'.
So, I can't expect where is the problem.

The error you're encountering seems related to the shapes of your tensors in the FactorInteractionLayer class. Specifically, the error message "Input to reshape is a tensor with 28 values, but the requested shape has 128" indicates that there's a shape mismatch when TensorFlow tries to reshape a tensor.In your FactorInteractionLayer, you are concatenating embeddings (user_emb, item_emb, text_emb, visual_emb) and then passing them through layers (self.h, self.attention_layer) expecting certain output shapes.

Ensure that attention_weights has the correct dimensions to perform the weighted operations (tf.tensordot) properly. Verify that attention_weights has shape [batch_size, 3] after softmax.Double-check the configurations of Embedding layers (UserEmbedding and ItemEmbedding) in your main model function (DMRL). Ensure they output embeddings of the expected shape.
